# Android Studio and Google Drive API (Uploading video to Google Drive)

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I followed the quickstart guide from Google to take an image and afterwards upload it to the users Google Drive.

My question is, how can i adapt this to using video and uploading video to Google Drive instead of an image? I already know how to access and record video's using intents (and saving it on the external storage) but not how to upload afterwards. My guess is it would be pretty much the same as the following code, but again not sure.

Any help will be appreciated!

```
/**
 * Android Drive Quickstart activity. This activity takes a photo and saves it
 * in Google Drive. The user is prompted with a pre-made dialog which allows
 * them to choose the file location.
 */
public class Main2Activity extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks,
        OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "drive-quickstart";
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR = 2;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION = 3;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Bitmap mBitmapToSave;


    /**
     * Create a new file and save it to Drive.
     */

    private void saveFileToDrive() {
        // Start by creating a new contents, and setting a callback.
        Log.i(TAG, "Creating new contents.");
        final Bitmap image = mBitmapToSave;
        Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResult(DriveContentsResult result) {
                        // If the operation was not successful, we cannot do anything
                        // and must
                        // fail.
                        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Failed to create new contents.");
                            return;
                        }
                        // Otherwise, we can write our data to the new contents.
                        Log.i(TAG, "New contents created.");
                        // Get an output stream for the contents.
                        OutputStream outputStream = result.getDriveContents().getOutputStream();
                        // Write the bitmap data from it.
                        ByteArrayOutputStream bitmapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bitmapStream);
                        try {
                            outputStream.write(bitmapStream.toByteArray());
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Unable to write file contents.");
                        }
                        // Create the initial metadata - MIME type and title.
                        // Note that the user will be able to change the title later.
                        MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                                .setMimeType("image/jpeg").setTitle("Android Photo.png").build();
                        // Create an intent for the file chooser, and start it.
                        IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                                .newCreateFileActivityBuilder()
                                .setInitialMetadata(metadataChangeSet)
                                .setInitialDriveContents(result.getDriveContents())
                                .build(mGoogleApiClient);
                        try {
                            startIntentSenderForResult(
                                    intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR, null, 0, 0, 0);
                        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Failed to launch file chooser.");
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            // Create the API client and bind it to an instance variable.
            // We use this instance as the callback for connection and connection
            // failures.
            // Since no account name is passed, the user is prompted to choose.
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Drive.API)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
        }
        // Connect the client. Once connected, the camera is launched.
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE:
                // Called after a photo has been taken.
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // Store the image data as a bitmap for writing later.
                    mBitmapToSave = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR:
                // Called after a file is saved to Drive.
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Image successfully saved.");
                    mBitmapToSave = null;
                    // Just start the camera again for another photo.
                    startActivityForResult(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE),
                            REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // Called whenever the API client fails to connect.
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result.toString());
        if (!result.hasResolution()) {
            // show the localized error dialog.
            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, result.getErrorCode(), 0).show();
            return;
        }
        // The failure has a resolution. Resolve it.
        // Called typically when the app is not yet authorized, and an
        // authorization
        // dialog is displayed to the user.
        try {
            result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Log.i(TAG, "API client connected.");
        if (mBitmapToSave == null) {
            // This activity has no UI of its own. Just start the camera.
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE),
                    REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE);
            return;
        }
        saveFileToDrive();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection suspended");
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason this could not be included

Answer (score 0):

In the code snippet, you can try to change the mimeType to `application/vnd.google-apps.video` and the `Bitmap` typecast to (lets say) `byte[]`. I'm just not certain since this involves possibly large files and there's no documentation on the Android Drive API page about video uploads.

There are other ways to approach this, though. What I can suggest is for you to utilize the REST calls in [uploading files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads).

For videos (which usually has a large file size), I'd suggest you use Resumable Uploads. It does have some prerequisites you'll need to do

> The steps for using resumable upload include:
>
> 1. Start a resumable session. Make an initial request to the upload URI that includes the metadata, if any.
> 2. Save the resumable session URI. Save the session URI returned in the response of the initial request; you'll use it for the remaining requests in this session.
> 3. Upload the file. Send the media file to the resumable session URI.

More information can be found on the documentation.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am trying hard to figure the resuamble code out. I am a noob programmer haha. When i try to write the code and follow the instructions it is filled with red marks underneath. Some need to be imported. Some have multiple import options. A bit confusing :I

Comment: Sorry but i simply have no idea what to do whatsoever. Haha i seem pretty lost. There are so little information about uploading anything and when i finally find anything it has nothing to do with videos at all